# Wordpress : Add 1 to a variable each time a new post is published

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to detect when the post of a member is published ?

I would like to add 1 to a variable each time a new post is published.

```
if(new_post_of_specific_user_is_published) {
$variable = $variable + 1;
}
```

Comment: What is your reason for wanting to "add 1 to a variable each time a new post is published"?

Comment: It's is a piggy bank to thank the member as soon as he posted a post.

Comment: What does that mean? When a member posts something, what do you expect should happen? Doing `$variable = $variable + 1;` in isolation has no effect.

Comment: From a certain amount, a discount is offered for example.

Comment: I'm still not totally sure what you're trying to do, but it's probably better to just count the user's published posts whenever you want to know how many there are.

Comment: No it's slightly different. I want to detect when a post is published to add 1 to the variable of the member who created this post. Thanks for your help !

Comment: You're not being clear. "Adding 1 to a variable" isn't something that anybody wants to do, and variables don't exist unless some code is running. What _action_ should be triggered when a post is published? Should an email get sent? Should a notice be posted on the site? Should some arbitrary code be run? **This is almost certainly an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)**.

Comment: To be more specific, I want to add a specific value to a meta user each time this user adds a new post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the piggy bank as a user meta and each time the members post a new post use the save_post or save_post_custom_post_type filter to add the user meta.

```
add_action( 'save_post_piggy_bank', 'my_function', 10, 2 );
function my_function($post_id, $post){
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) return;
    if($post->post_status == 'auto-draft' || $post->post_status == 'trash'){
        return;
    }

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    //get the user's piggy bank
    $piggy_bank_amount = get_user_meta($user_id, 'piggy_bank', true);

    //increment their bank by 1
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'piggy_bank', $piggy_bank_amount + 1);
}
```

Comment: if i could profit from that, i would abuse the shit out of it... counting actual posts in the dbase for that allows for moderator inverventions and deletes to count in the total at all times, simply. hf m8!

Comment: But if the user wants to send an email every time a new post is submitted (or something similar, which would require the exact moment), you would need to hook into the save_post action.

Comment: I agree, bad way to count but that's what the OP asked.

Comment: To be more specific, I want to add 1 to a meta user each time this user adds a new post publish.

Comment: How to run this function when a post is created ?

Comment: Put it in your functions.php file of your child theme. If you have not setup a child theme, I would highly recommend it: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: Yes it's done ! But this does not seem functional. Maybe because it is a post type 'coupons' and not a classic post.

Comment: Yes, if you need to catch a custom post type use the save_post_(custom type here) filter. So yours would be: `add_action( 'save_post_coupons', 'my_function', 10, 2 );`

Comment: Or probably because the post is created on hold by default and I edited the post to be published once. It is at this edition that the function should start. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2):

you dont need a variable.. a variable is not persistent. you can know how many posts a user has posted though. at any time

```
$user_post_count = count_user_posts( $userid , $post_type );
```

yout post type will most likely be 'post'

Comment: Please don't add extraneous comments about having fun, signatures, etc. to your posts. Feel free to add them to your profile page, which your automatic signature links to. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28416/what-is-the-policy-on-signatures-and-links-in-answers and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed.